# Reset initial ComboBox text when revisiting

Tags: vba, search, combobox, menu, powerpoint

Firstly let me say I am a SERIOUS beginner with code - everything I've written here I've cobbled together from hours of YouTube, forums and trial and error - so I don't actually know what I'm doing! Hence, please be gentle with any responses!!! (and bear with me if I ask stupid questions/for clarification).

I'm working in PowerPoint (a product knowledge job aid)...I'm putting in a drop down menu on the home slide, and when an item in the list is selected, it takes the user to a specific slide. I've got that far (by some miracle!) with the code below.

```
Sub AddDropDownItems()
ComboBox1.AddItem "mesh"
ComboBox1.AddItem "reo"
ComboBox1.AddItem "tape"
ComboBox1.AddItem "film"
ComboBox1.AddItem "tube"
ComboBox1.ListRows = 5
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
Case Is = "mesh"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
Case Is = "reo"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 3
Case Is = "tape"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 4
Case Is = "film"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 5
Case Is = "tube"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 6
End Select
End Sub
```

Each slide the user goes to, has a hyperlink back to the "home" menu slide.

I selected and edited the "ComboBox Options" and typed in the initial display text of "Product search"... but when the slide is returned to, the previous selection remains in the ComboBox and the initial text has disappeared.

Is there a way to reset the box when the slide is revisited?

I tried a cheeky workaround of putting a simple text box on top of the combo box but that doesn't show in slideshow mode for some reason!

It's also worth noting that the final product list will include 50+ slides, so if anyone knows of an easier menu/search function I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: After each line in your `Case` can you add `Me.ComboBox1.Value = ""`?

Comment: This is great and working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you want the combobox to return to it's default value, but you just need to add this where you want the change to happen.  Maybe where dwirony stated, but you need to reference the index of the combobox.

```
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
```

This will set the combobox selection to the first entry or item.